# docker: invalid reference format using ${PWD} on WIndows

Tags: docker, git-bash

I want to run docker container (Windows) using the following shell file configuration:

```
# Variables
model="Llama-2-7b-chat"
volume="$PWD/data"

# Echo starting message
echo "Starting the Docker container with local files (No Internet): $model and volume: $volume ..."

# Start the Docker container
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash -itd \
  --name $model \
  -v $volume:/data \
  -p 8080:80 ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:latest
```

When I start .sh script I get the following error:

```
$ ./run_llama_2.sh
Starting the Docker container with local files (No Internet): Llama-2-7b-chat and volume: /c/Users/user_name/llama_chat/data ...
docker: invalid reference format.
```

It has something to do with `volume="$PWD/data"`. How can I correct the format?

Comment: Quote your variables! `-v "$volume:/data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand your variables:

```bash
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash -itd \
  --name "$model" \
  -v "$volume":/data \
  -p 8080:80 ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:latest
```